# How to install Symfony 2.6 in windows 8 successfully?

Tags: php, windows, symfony-2.6

When i tried this command

```
php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

Im getting this error

[image]

But i have given permission to C: Directry to Write & execute

Comment: Wrong inner quotes maybe? Have you tried another directory? Another system disk?

Comment: yes ,
Other directries i cannot install ,Im getting this error

'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you added the path to the `PHP` executable in your `environment` variable?

Comment: I forgot and then  I added the path but command successfully  executed. but it didnt download the symfony.phar

Comment: Symfony2 is installed in your directory? Are you talking about `composer.phar`?

Comment: The easy way to install symfony is through composer. You need to have composer available on windows command prompt. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/composer.html

Comment: @D4V1D no it didnt install,when i execute the command it just create a symfony.file Not intaller

Comment: @ Gopakumar Gopalan
I tried your way too.When i execute D:\>php symfony
Im getting this error 
Notice: Undefined index: PATH in phar://D:/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/AboutC
mmand.php on line 106